# How to resize CKEditor to fit its parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have a CKeditor which is placed in a parent div. What is the best way to have the CKEditor exactly fit the div and resize when the div resizes? If possible I would prefer solutions which don't involve jQuery. If this is not possible solutions using jQuery would be fine to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );
```

...

And then, in event of your choice, do this:

```
editor.resize($("#elem").width(),$("#elem").height());
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Use the width attribute when you call ckeditor.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

CKEDITOR.replace( 'page_content',
{
    toolbar : 'MyToolbar',
    width : '100%'


});

//]]>
</script>
```

Since the call to initialize the editor is done with jquery, this is the best way.

edit: This will cause ckeditor to auto-resize when the div width changes as well.

Comment: I tried that but it still leaves the CKEditor with a fixed height. How can I fit the height as well?

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs this now, I added this to my css file:

```
#cke_id_text {
  width: fit-content!important;
}
```